# How to add a value to a form field before rendering the form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm building a website whose purpose is to deliver food. I have a model "Plat" representing a meal and a model "Commande" representing an order. In the website, the user can look at a meal, then click on a button "make an order" and finally fill a form with the order details. "Commande" has multiple fields and one of them is "plat" that link the order to the meal. My problem is that I need to fill the "plat" field of the "Commande" model before rendering the form because I have a validation rule that depends on a field of the "Plat" model : in the "Commande" form, the customer can choose the number of parts of the meal he want, and if this number is greater than the number of parts availables (parts_available is a filed of "Plat"), it raises an error.

I have tried to do it this way (see below) but that doesn't work, when the customer save the "Commande" form, it raises an AttributeError because it try to access a field of plat but plat is equal to None. Do you have any idea how I can do what I want ?

Thanks in advance !

models.py

```
class Plat(models.Model):
    SOME FIELDS
    nb_portions = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "Nombre de portions disponibles") # the number of parts available

class Commande(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    plat = models.ForeignKey('Plat', on_delete = models.CASCADE) # models.PROTECT pour pas supprimer, models.CASCADE pour supprimer.
    nb_portions = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "Nombre de portions")
```

forms.py

```
class CommandeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Commande
        fields = ['nb_portions', 'adresse_livraison']
        widgets = {'nb_portions': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                    'adresse_livraison': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})}
        labels = {'adresse_livraison': 'Adresse de livraison (livraison à partir de 5 portions) :'}

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(CommandeForm, self).clean()
        plat = cleaned_data.get('plat')
        nb_portions = cleaned_data.get('nb_portions')

        if nb_portions > plat.nb_portions:
            self.add_error("Le nombre de portions maximales disponibles pour ce plat est : " + str(plat.nb_portions) + " portions.")

        return cleaned_data
```

views.py

```
def commander(request, id):
    plat = get_object_or_404(Plat, id=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommandeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            commande = form.save(commit = False)
            commande.user = request.user
            commande.plat = plat
            commande.save()
            return redirect(commande_validee)
    else:
        commande = CommandeForm()
        commande.plat = plat
        form = commande

    return render(request, 'actualites/commander.html', locals())
```

EDIT :

I have copy-pasted the **init** method suggested by dirkgroten in the CommandeForm and modified the view accordingly :

```
def commander(request, id):
    plat = get_object_or_404(Plat, id=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommandeForm(request.POST, plat=plat)
        if form.is_valid():
            commande = form.save(commit = False)
            commande.user = request.user
            commande.date = plat.date_prep
            commande.save()
            return redirect(commande_validee)
    else:
        form = CommandeForm(plat=plat)

    return render(request, 'actualites/commander.html', locals())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form's `cleaned_data` doesn't have an attribute `plat` because it isn't a field in your form. You should pass `plat` as extra parameter to your form's `init` method so you can use it later:

```
form = CommandeForm(request.POST, plat=plat)

class CommandeForm(...):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.plat = kwargs.pop('plat', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        ...
        if self.plat and nb_portions > self.plat.nb_portions:
            ...
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't notice that plat wasn't a field in my form ! However I still have the error, I may have misunderstood your answer. So I have added the __init__ method to the CommandeForm and I have modified the view as you can see in the EDIT section of my post. I don't see what I'm doing wrong, it seems to me that it should work

Comment: You also changed your `clean()` method?

Comment: No what do I have to change ? I'v tried removing the line ```plat = cleaned_data.get('plat')``` but it obviously didn't recognize the variable plat anymore. I guess I have to get the value of plat in an other way than using cleaned_data ?

Comment: it's in my answer, use `self.plat` instead of `plat = self.cleaned_data.get('plat')`. You assigned `self.plat` in the init method, so it's available in the `clean()` method.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see it... That works now, the error is correctly dispayed when the number of parts is to great. But I still have an error when I submit the form : ```NOT NULL constraint failed: actualites_commande.plat_id```. I've tried solving it by adding back the line ```commande.plat = plat``` in the view but it gives me a ```UNIQUE constraint failed```

Comment: yep, you should have `commande.plat = plat` in your view before `commande.save()`. That should work. Not sure the `UNIQUE constraint failed` error is related to this in any way. You might want to post a new question and show the full error trace.

Comment: oh, I see, there can only be one `Commande` for one `User` because you're using a `OneToOneField`. Are you sure that's the desired behavior?

Comment: Yes you are right it isn't the desired behavior. I'm sorry I'm tired and I make stupid mistakes. Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: I'm sorry I'm coming back because I don't find the answer myself. I have changed the relation like this : ```user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)``` so everything should work now but I still have the same ```NOT NULL constraint failed``` error. It's strange because the Commande table of the database is empty so even if one user could only take one Commande, it's supposed to work for the first Commande object creation but it isn't... This question is off topic so maybe we can move to chat ?

Comment: You should post a new question and include the full error trace as more information is needed. Can’t help further now.